# Plugin solution with gwt

Tags: gwt, plugins

We have a closed source gwt application/framework which we distribute to different partrens which then install it on their own servers.

Now we want to allow third party developers to write plugins to our application, which our partners can then install.

What is the best way to do this, and is it even possible without distributing our java code?

Our application does for example have an interface called SpecialMagicPageInterface. A third party developer can then develop an Page which implement this interface, and our software should then be able to create an object of this type at runtime, and call methods on it.

Is this even possible, if the third party only have our interface, and not the entire application, and if yes how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Design your app framework in this way:

1. Write interfaces like MagicInterface1, MagicInterface2 etc and JAR it up with source and class files in the same JAR. You can distribute this JAR because it contains only interfaces.
2. Write your application in another project/JAR and do not distribute this JAR, build the compiled, minified, obfuscated javascript from this JAR. - Obviously this JAR will depend on the previous JAR which contains all the interfaces.
3. Now PACKAGE the generated javascript together with the 1st JAR with interfaces into a zip and give to plugin developers.
4. They can compile their GWT projects - their plugin code will depend on your interface JAR, and their plugin project will also end up as a javascript file.
5. In the final application make sure you reference your framework script file first, and then reference all the plugin script file one after the other.

Result:

- Plugin devs see only the minified JS of your framework, yet they can create plugins.
- The framework project and the various plugin projects each have one JS file each.
- All the JS files are referenced in the final app, in the correct order
- Code in the framework is written in such a way that it FINDS AND INSTANTIATES all the plugins that exist after document is loaded.

Comment: Sorry about the late delay, but I got pulled away for an other emergency problem. But are you sure that solution will work. According to http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/4a3f912cb89a7256 what I want can't really be done. But I will have time took look at gwt again in 2 weeks, and then I will try to implement what you described.